# Swift 2, iTunes file sharing

Tags: swift, file, itunes, sharing

I have an app written in Swift 2. Application Supports iTunes file sharing is set to YES. When I connect my iPad to iTunes the app does not appear in the File Sharing list. iTunes version, 12.3.1.23, Xcode version 7.1.1(7B1005).

Any suggestions?

I am using Core Data so expect to see SQLite files.

Comment: try creating a new project

Comment: Aloha Leo, by creating anew project do you mean giving the existing project a new name or rewriting the entire app?

Comment: just drag the files from the old  one to the new one at another location

Comment: Aloha Leo,  Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Thanks Leo, it worked, but that begs the question, why did the original project name not work?

Comment: I have no idea. I had a similar problem that I had to do the same

Comment: Aloha Leo, I found another solution from a Stack Overflow post in November 2014. His solution was to copy ${PRODUCT_NAME} from the Bundle Name in the info pList and paste it into the Bundle Display Name. I tried it and it works.

Comment: Try rebooting the device. For the old app. Things can get messed up, sometimes just needs a reboot.